# Volume overlap of two convex hulls

Tags: python, overlap, scikit-image, shapely, convex-hull

I have two sets of points which I can transform into a 3D convex hull via skimage's [convex hull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html) function. Is there some computationally efficient way with which to determine the overlap volume of the two 3D hulls formed this way?

Thanks

Comment: have you looked at polygon mesh boolean operations ?

Comment: I am not well acquainted with the packages available in this context. Is it possible for me to do this via pymesh? The data format I have is just a bunch of points, so if it was possible to generate a pymesh around this convex hull then that would be ideal.

Comment: I am not familiar with the packages as well. But i've looked at the scipy convex hull documentation and it should be pretty easy to generate a pymesh from the vertices and simplices arrays you get from the convex hull algorithm.

mesh = pymesh.form_mesh(vertices, faces)

you can probably plug the simplices into the faces parameter. But you have to check if the format is correct. And this only works in with 3d convex hulls.

A Simplex is just the generalization of a triangle for n dimensions

Comment: I have managed to create a union mesh in pymesh, but how would i generate a volume from that? I did not see an attribute in the docs to compute the volume of a mesh.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing insights from the comments:

First, I think you are interested in the *intersection* mesh, not the union. Once you have the vertices for the intersection mesh, I believe you can simply calculate the convex hull volume of that mesh using scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).